Im getting an error when trying to use NMS on spigot
Im getting this error when trying to use nms on spigot 1.20.4
For this one I tried in artifactID removing -api like a saw in a tutorial.
Here is part of my pom.xml file:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

Error:
Unresolved dependency: 'org.spigotmc:spigot:jar:1.20.4-R01-SNAPSHOT'

Could not find artifact org.spigotmc:spigot:jar:1.20.4-R01-SNAPSHOT in spigotmc-repo (https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/)

Try to run Maven import with -U flag (force update snapshots)

I also tried using spigot-server
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot-server</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

With this error
[WARNING] The POM for org.spigotmc:spigot-server:jar:1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
Cannot resolve org.spigotmc:spigot-server:1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT

Could not find artifact org.spigotmc:spigot-server:pom:1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT in spigotmc-repo (https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/)
Could not find artifact org.spigotmc:spigot-server:pom:1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT in spigotmc-repo (https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/)

Could not find artifact org.spigotmc:spigot-server:jar:1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT in spigotmc-repo (https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/)

Try to run Maven import with -U flag (force update snapshots)


The right one is with spigot, like this:
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
        <artifactId>spigot</artifactId>
        <version>1.20.4-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <classifier>remapped-mojang</classifier>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

But, to make it possible to find, you have to you BuildTools by using this command:
java -jar BuildTools.jar --rev 1.20.4 --remapped

(You will need Java 17 or more)
Then, after the build end, the spigot version will be available on local repository (at %HOMEDIR%/.m2/repository/org/spigotmc/spigot/1.20.4.). Now you can refresh the project.
More informations here.

I am still getting the same error

And the build tools well finish? You're getting exactly the same error of it changed?
